# Display an image only - no other page content in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to ***display a static page with an image*** in **wordpress**.

*I got a blog theme and I could display the image 
but all other details like post, etc are displayed together.*

How can I remove that?

Is there  any theme for single image display

Comment: Do you want the header / footer of the site to show? It might help to be a bit more descriptive - maybe take screenshots of how it looks vs a mockup of how you want it to look.

Comment: I dont want header or footer . I just need to show only one image.

Comment: Could you not just link to the image itself then?

Comment: You should post your own research efforts. How did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: sure.....i will upload it

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new template by copying the existing one.
2. Remove header and footer and sidebar etc. from template code.
3. Assign this template to a page you create, which contains the image to show.
4. Possibly add custom CSS to get the right look.

See https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page and a php file named `page-{slug}.php` where "slug" is the actual slug of the page. There you can add your custom code, for example just showing an image. Something along the lines of:

```
<?php
  echo '<img src="' . the_post_thumbnail() . '">';
```

I'm assuming you want the featured image, otherwise something like:

```
<?php
  echo '<img src="https://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads...">';
```

This way will give you full programatic control over the page, otherwise **jasie**' suggestion is better.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [the BlankSlate theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/blankslate/) as a starting point. You can create a child theme of it (per @jasie's answer) to remove things like the site title and search bar, then be left with *just* the image.